# Emscripten missing epoll.h when compiling grpc library to wasm(Webassembly)

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I'm going to convert a c++ project that needs to use the **grpc library** to **wasm** using **Emscripten**. As far as I know, the grpc source code needs to be compiled using Emscripten to get the library.

By the way, I want to compile grpc lib for **standalone** wasm binary and run it using runtime(for example, wasmtime).

**The error below has been resolved and can go to *Update2***.

But there was an **error** when compiling the grpc source code:

```
[  7%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_bad_variant_access.a
[  7%] Built target bad_variant_access
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o
In file included from /home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc:19:
/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:451:2: error: "Could not auto-detect platform"
#error "Could not auto-detect platform"
 ^
/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:474:2: warning: "GPR_PLATFORM_STRING not auto-detected" [-W#warnings]
#warning "GPR_PLATFORM_STRING not auto-detected"
 ^
/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:541:2: error: Must define exactly one of GPR_GCC_ATOMIC, GPR_GCC_SYNC, GPR_WINDOWS_ATOMIC
#error Must define exactly one of GPR_GCC_ATOMIC, GPR_GCC_SYNC, GPR_WINDOWS_ATOMIC
 ^
/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:545:2: error: Must define exactly one of GPR_ARCH_32, GPR_ARCH_64
#error Must define exactly one of GPR_ARCH_32, GPR_ARCH_64
 ^
/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:551:2: error: Must define exactly one of GPR_CPU_LINUX, GPR_CPU_POSIX, GPR_WINDOWS, GPR_CPU_IPHONE, GPR_CPU_CUSTOM
#error Must define exactly one of GPR_CPU_LINUX, GPR_CPU_POSIX, GPR_WINDOWS, GPR_CPU_IPHONE, GPR_CPU_CUSTOM
 ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
em++: error: '/home/xxx/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang++ -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -fvisibility=default -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mlm -disable-lsr -DEMSCRIPTEN -I/home/xxx/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/SDL --sysroot=/home/xxx/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/compat -I/home/xxx/grpcasm/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/zlib -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/include -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/re2 -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/src/core/e/upbdefs-generated -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/upb -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/xxhash -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/zlib -I/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/third_party/abil-cpp -fPIC -std=c++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o.d -c /home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc -o CMakeFiles/gpr.d/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o' failed (returned 1)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/build.make:77: CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1046: CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
emmake: error: 'make' failed (returned 2)
```

I export `GRPC_CROSS_COMPILATION=true` and `GRPC_CROSS_AROPTS=cr --target=wasm32-wasi` but it didn't seem to work.

**Update:**

Noticed a warning:

```
CMake Warning at third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/copts/AbseilConfigureCopts.cmake:70 (message):
  Value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR (x86) is unknown and cannot be used to set
  ABSL_RANDOM_RANDEN_COPTS
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/abseil-cpp/CMake/AbseilHelpers.cmake:18 (include)
  third_party/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:81 (include)
```

So I set the platform parameter for Emscripten cmake: `-DEMSCRIPTEN_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64` but it doesn't seem to work.

Cmake command parameter is:

```
emcmake cmake ../..  
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/xxx/grpc_wasm/grpc/mylib 
-DEMSCRIPTEN_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-mrelaxed-simd 
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-mrelaxed-simd 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Relese 
-DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package 
-DProtobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/xxx/protobuf_wasm/protobuf_src/src 
-DProtobuf_LIBRARIES=/home/xxx/protobuf_wasm/protobuf_src/src/.libs 
-DProtobuf_PROTOC_LIBRARY:/home/xxx/protobuf_wasm/protobuf_src/src/.libs
```

Since I have already compiled the protobuf lib using Emscripten, I specify the lib and include directory of libprotobuf manually.

**Update2:**

About the `error: "Could not auto-detect platform"`, I add `#define __linux__ 1` in grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h.

After that, I went through another error: **emscripten libc lacks of epoll.h** (details and what I have done can be found in [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/18671)).

I created epoll.h and eventfd.h in `emsdk include/sys` directory, although the compilation of grpc is successful and got libgrpc.a, I got error of **undefined symbol** in the link phase as expected (also [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/18671)). This is because the libc doesn't have the defination of functions in epoll.h and eventfd.h.

It turns out that the Emscripten libc doesn't support epoll system call, and I faild to recompile the libc (also [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/18671)) to support that.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve the epoll problem? Appreciate any reply and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can't just compile gRPC on emscripten because it contains low level platform optimizations. You need to port it to emscripten, modifing grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h and other files. Is it possible to call grpc-web
 using EM_ASM?

Comment: @zakki Thank you for your reply. So sorry I forgot to mention that I want to compile grpc lib for standalone wasm binary and run it using wasmtime.